# Adding Multiple QGraphicsItem to QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qlist

I am trying to add multiple `qgraphicsitem` to a `qgraphicsitemgroup` as:

```
case LineMode:
    lineGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup;
    if (c1)
    {
        pointItem = new Point;
        pointItem->setPos(mouseEvent->scenePos());
        lineGroup->addToGroup(pointItem);
        start_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
        c1 = false;
        c2 = true;
        qDebug() << "p1: " << lineGroup->childItems().count();
    }

    else if (!c1 && c2)
    {
        pointItem = new Point;
        pointItem->setPos(mouseEvent->scenePos());
        lineGroup->addToGroup(pointItem);
        end_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
        c3 = true;
        c2 = false;
        qDebug() << "p2:" << lineGroup->childItems().count();
    }

    if (c3)
    {
        lineItem = new Line(start_p, end_p);
        lineGroup->addToGroup(lineItem);
        addItem(lineGroup);
        groupList.append(lineGroup);
        qDebug() << "p3:" << lineGroup->childItems().count();
    }
    break;
```

I have created `groupList` in header file as:

```
QList<QGraphicsItemGroup*> groupList;
```

The count of items added to the group remains 1 even after adding 3 items, i.e

```
p1: 1
p2: 1
p3: 1
```

Also the first item added is not being displayed.

[image: This is what I want]
[image: This is what I am getting]

The left image is the expected output whereas I am getting the right one.
How to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you surprised that there is only 1 item inside the group when you create a new group every time in your `switch` statement?

Comment: @thuga There are 3 items that are constituting a line. Therefore, `lineGroup` must have these 3 items. I want these 3 items(pointItem1, pointItem2, lineItem) to be added as single `lineGroup`.

Comment: Then you should create a new group only when adding the 1st point. Each point shouldn't be in their own group, that would be silly. Move the creation of new `QGraphicsItemGroup` to `if(c1)`. This is if you can guarantee that this is the 1st `if` statement that will be true. You should also check that `lineGroup` has been created in other `if`/`else if` blocks.

Comment: I already tried that :( and it resulted in segmentation fault pointing to the `lineGroup->addToGroup(pointItem);` in second if block.

Comment: Did you check if it went inside the `if(c1)` block at any point before entering `else if(!c1 && c2)`?

Comment: Yes, It does enter the if(c1) block.

Comment: Something seems to destroy your `lineGroup`. Unless you're using a local variable with the same name.